# Select and compare populations

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like that:

```
data=data.frame(
  EyeCol=c("blue","blue","blue","green","green","brown","brown","brown","brown","amber","amber","amber","amber"),
  BodyShape=c("skinny","fat","skinny","skinny","skinny","fat","fat","fat","regular","regular","regular","skinny","regular"),
  value=rnorm(n = 13)
)
> data
      EyeCol  BodyShape value                
 [1,] "blue"  "skinny"  "-0.151764111069661" 
 [2,] "blue"  "fat"     "0.68161499165021"   
 [3,] "blue"  "skinny"  "2.45634829248442"   
 [4,] "green" "skinny"  "2.40305139602346"   
 [5,] "green" "skinny"  "-0.490136912577361" 
 [6,] "brown" "fat"     "-0.552026475080878" 
 [7,] "brown" "fat"     "0.466500574627706"  
 [8,] "brown" "fat"     "0.133980090309033"  
 [9,] "brown" "regular" "-0.801840913223832" 
[10,] "amber" "regular" "-0.0484879443196371"
[11,] "amber" "regular" "0.0269352552010763" 
[12,] "amber" "skinny"  "-1.12761016311858"  
[13,] "amber" "regular" "1.857866986502"
```

I have to compare all possible combinations, ie: G*reen-eyes Regular-Bodysite .versus. Brown-eyes Skinny-Bodysite*

But I have to avoid self-comparisons an redundant ones (*Green Regular .versus. Brown Skinny* is the same as  *Brown Skinny .versus. Green Regular*)

Currently, I am building a data frame that guide the selection

```
EyeCol=c("blue","green","brown","amber")
BodyShape=c("skinny","regular","fat")

expand.grid(list(ec.x=EyeCol,bs.x=BodyShape,ec.y=EyeCol,bs.y=BodyShape))
```

Then I delete lines what don't matter: self-comparisons and reciprocal ones.

Last but not the least, I may have N factors (here 2 bodyshape and eyecolor).

Does anyone has a elegant way to do this and not time consuming since my data has about 5k row and the number of factor currently reach 7.

Comment: `[1,] ...` shows that your object `data` is a matrix (not a dataframe). What kind of comparisation you want to do? `xtabs()` ?

Comment: Maybe: `combn(paste(df1$EyeCol, df1$BodyShape, sep = "_"), 2)` ?